# My site width is wider then I need?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

So if anyone could help I would be greatful, but I am just finishing up my portfolio site [www.tylerRdesigns.com](http://www.tylerrdesigns.com) and for some reason when you are on a browser there is an extra 20 -30pixels of space to the right.  So it makes for an annoying scroll experience when you are on a phone or computer.

I used bootstrap to create my navigation bar, but the rest was coded from scratch, and all my widths are set at 100% so I am confused as to why that extra space is there.

If someone could take a look at my site and check out the code it is live, and I would really appreciate it.  My best guess is it is something in my navigation bar, but I can't figure out why it is going beyond 100% width?

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't include .container class before .row class

Comment: This type of question is off-topic for SO, but to help you out a little, get familiar with your browser's developer tools, they'll quickly point you in the right direction http://i.imgur.com/EnaZEnh.png

Comment: You need to wrap up all your row classes inside a container class or get rid of the default negetive margin on all row classes by overiding default bootstrap class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just remove some `row` from `About Grid`, `About Background` and end of `About me` section OR add `container-fluid` over the `row`. Try it

Comment: That seemed to work when the screen size is at a desktop width, so thank you! But when it is down to mobile there is still a space to the right again?

Comment: I checked here, its showing fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Some things are not defined:

Display them in your console

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: jQuery is not defined
(index):103GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/close.png 404 (Not Found)
(index):103GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/loading.gif 404 (Not Found)
(index):103GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/prev.png 404 (Not Found)
(index):103GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/next.png 404 (Not Found)
(index):1 GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/js/lightbox.min.map 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/prev.png 404 (Not Found)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 a.getComputedStyle.Jbjquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.extend.cssjquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.accessjquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 m.fn.extend.csslightbox.min.js:9 b.buildlightbox.min.js:9 b.initlightbox.min.js:9 blightbox.min.js:9 (anonymous function)jquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.jjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 m.Callbacks.k.fireWithjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 m.extend.readyjquery-1.11.2.min.js:2 J
jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/next.png 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/loading.gif 404 (Not Found)
jquery-1.11.2.min.js:3 GET http://www.tylerrdesigns.com/img/close.png 404 (Not Found)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have 30 pixels of padding on  right after your div with an ID of "resumeCircle".

You can use a tool like firebug or web developer tools in chrome to debug your code. That's all I did.

Answer (score 0):

This can be solved using `Twitter Bootstrap`. It utilizes a grid layout to break a page down into 12 columns. I was looking at the images gallery, with 5 images per row. This is where your problem lies.

It should be broken down as follows

```
  Margin col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-2 col-md-2 Margin
```

Each image will take up 2 columns of space. 2 x 5 = 10. That accounts for 10 out of the 12 columns. How do we account for the other 2 columns? Use the `col-md-1-offset` class

Your code would look like so

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2 col-md-offset-1">
      Images
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Images
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Images
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Images
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
      Images
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Just apply

```
overflow-y:hidden;
```

to #video-container if you would like a quick fix.

It's happening because the height on your .header-unit class is 850px and the picture within #video-container is larger than that.

Comment: That's a sloppy fix.

Comment: So is applying absolute positioning and floats unnecessarily all over the page, and I'm certainly not going to review the entirety of the code and fix it all, which at looking briefly, needs a lot of work.

Comment: Im new at web designing, so take it easy, but I feel like the styling I wanted to do was always over taken by bootstrap's.  I initially wanted to just use the bootstrap responsive navigation bar and style the rest on my own.

Answer (score -1):

You are using bootstrap. When using a `row` class on an element, you have to wrap it in a `.container` element.

See [the doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container).